# Find list of words in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, text

I am trying to search a dictionary for a list of words and output the matched words in the dictionary and key. Here is my workable code:

```
word_search = 'sun'
text_dict = {'1: This is the sun.',  2: 'Tomorrow will be windy', 3: 'I went to the park.'}
bin = []

for key, value in text_dict.items():
  if word_search in value:
  bin.append(key)
  bin.append(word_search)
return bin
```

```
Output: [1, sun]
```

This works with single string 'sun'. How can I make a LIST work in this function?

```
word_search = ['sun', 'park']
```

```
Output: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left
```

Thanks!

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and `in` operators to determine if elements in the list exist in the `key,value` pair.

```
[(key, word) for word in word_search for key, value in text_dict.items() if word in value]
#[(1, 'sun'), (3, 'park')]
```